# Aliasing an imported font to be reused later?

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I have imported a font from files and set it as the main font like this:

```
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}[
Path = fonts/eb-garamond/,
Extension = .ttf,
UprightFont = *12-Regular,
BoldFont = *08-Regular,
ItalicFont = *12-Italic,
BoldItalicFont  = *08-Italic]
```

I now wish to assign an alias to this, so that I can change the main font to something else and then come back to this without repeating this whole block again. I cannot seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: Why don't you use `\newfontfamily\ebgaramondfamily...` rather than `\setmainfont`, if you don't want it as the main document font?

Comment: I basically wish for the option to swap main fonts later by using aliases. If I replace `\setmainfont` with `\newfontfamily\ebgaramondfamily`, and then do `\setmainfont{\ebgaramondfamily}`, the compilation freezes and never ends.

Comment: See my (again) edited answer. This doesn't work for XeLaTeX because I can't get EB Garamond to work with XeLaTeX at all - even if I just do `\setfontfamily...` and nothing else - not even using the font - XeLaTeX goes into infinite-spinning mode. However, the method works with XeLaTeX for a font which works for that engine.

Comment: You can put your settings in a file `myalias.fontspec`. See section 6.2. of the fontspec documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *many* ways to switch fonts using NFSS and fontspec commands. The other answers on this page are good and I'd suggest that @cfr's is probably the simplest and best; I just wanted to summarise everything that I could think of below.

---

Hooking into `\rmdefault` is probably a good idea, so I wouldn't recommend

```
\newfontfamily\mainone{...}[...]
\newfontfamily\maintwo{...}[...]
```

and switching between them with `\mainone` and `\maintwo` half-way through your text, since any internal command that requests `\rmfamily` will switch the font from what you've selected.

---

The next most simple method would be

```
\newcommand\switchone{%
  \setmainfont{...}[...]%
}
\newcommand\switchtwo{%
  \setmainfont{...}[...]%
}
```

and in the document you switch with `\switchone` and `\switchtwo`.
Slightly inefficient to process the options every time, but at least it's simple.
(Contrary to popular belief, re-running these commands shouldn't go about re-parsing and selecting the fonts from scratch, so it shouldn't be really that slow.)

---

Other answers have suggested variations on setting families and extracting the names used, either by writing

```
\setmainfont ...
\let\myfamone\rmfamily
...
\let\rmfamily\myfamone\normalfont
```

or extracting the family name from `\l_fontspec_family_tl`.

Here's another example along the same lines:

```
\newfontfamily\mainone{...}[NFSSFamily=rmone,...]
\newfontfamily\maintwo{...}[NFSSFamily=rmtwo,...]
\newcommand\switchmain[1]{\renewcommand\rmdefault{#1}\normalfont}
```

To switch between "default main fonts", you then need `\switchmain{rmone}` and `\switchmain{rmtwo}`. The benefit of this method is maximum flexibility.

---

Lastly, as Ulrike reminded me in the comments above, you can also use `.fontspec` files for this purpose. Normally `.fontspec` files are "supposed" to mirror the names of the fonts they're loading, but they can be completely abstract/semantic if you like. And in fact their contents don't need to be written in a separate file at all!

So you can switch main fonts using completely sensible markup without relying on defining additional commands using something like this:

```
\defaultfontfeatures[myfont]{
  Extension   = .otf ,
  UprightFont = texgyrepagella-regular ,
  BoldFont    = texgyrepagella-bold    ,
  % etc
}
...
\setmainfont{myfont}
\section{hello}
hello
```

In some ways I think this is the cleanest solution. I'll have to put my thinking cap to decide whether this interface is really ideal.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is the most readable one in my opinion. Hence marked as the correct answer. I never knew about the NFSSFamily option. That is exactly the 'alias' I was referring to :)

Comment: When I try to use multiple `\defaultfontfeatures` commands, I am getting an error: `"kernel/key-unknown"! The key 'fontspec/Path' is unknown and is being ignored.`

Comment: Sorry, this could be a bug — I'm away and can't check straight away. I've added it to the issue tracker: https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/216

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use `\newfontfamily` rather than `\setmainfont` if you do not want to use the font as the default serif for the document. For example (set up for EB Garamond is different because your settings are not suitable for my system):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\ebgaramondfamily{EB Garamond}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
  {\ebgaramondfamily
    \kant[2]
    \itshape\kant[3]
  }
  \kant[4]
\end{document}
```

Obviously, this would be a rather nasty mix, typographically, but for illustrative purposes the switch between Latin Modern and EBGaramond demonstrates the mechanism involved:

[image: font-switching]

## EDIT

If you want an easy way to switch the main document font, you can create a couple of convenience commands to change the default serif family although I'm not sure at all this is a good method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\ebgaramondfamily{EB Garamond}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\let\tgpdefaultfamily\rmfamily
\newcommand*\activateebg{%
  \let\rmfamily\ebgaramondfamily
  \rmfamily}
\newcommand*\activatetgp{%
  \let\rmfamily\tgpdefaultfamily
  \rmfamily}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
  \activateebg
  \kant[2]
  \itshape\kant[3]
  \activatetgp
  \kant[4]
  \upshape
  \kant[5]
\end{document}
```

[image: further font-switching]

**Edit:** XeLaTeX now works thanks to Thérèse's comment.

Comment: That’s odd.  I have no trouble with EB Garamond in either `luatex` or `xetex` (up-to-date “vanilla” TeX Live 2015 on Debian). Are you using the fonts from https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads (which I use), or those in TeX Live?  The latter don’t have the same file size as the former, and there’s a + added to the version number, so something was done to them that may be causing trouble.

Comment: @Thérèse So my example works for you with XeTeX? As I say, I can't figure a way to use EB Garamond at all in that case. I'm not sure which fonts I'm using though - hang on, I'll do some digging.

Comment: In your example, `xetex` seems to insist on a space between “EB” and “Garamond” (which I’ve always used anyway); `luatex` seems happy either way.

Comment: @Thérèse LuaTeX is using the TL 2015 versions. I checked and the versions I have in `/usr/share/fonts` are identical to the TL ones.

Comment: @Thérèse That's it! If I add the space, it works with XeTeX for me, too. But I do not understand why. If I run `otfinfo -i`, the only name matching `EB Garamond` is `Preferred family`. I earlier tried, for example `EB Garamond 12` (which is the `Family`) and `EB Garamond 12 Regular` (which is the `Full name`) but it did not occur to me to try the `Preferred` one. What is that? Most opentype fonts I've looked at don't even have an entry for that, so far as I remember.

Comment: @Thérèse Is there a way to tell which fonts XeTeX is using?

Comment: If it’s not in the log somewhere, I think `~/.fonts` is checked before `/usr/share/fonts`, so I assume the version there is being used.  And a document with small sizes should use EB Garamond 08 automatically; that’s not in TeX Live, for reasons unknown.

Comment: @Thérèse You mean that should be set up? I don't have those fonts at all. Nor do I have any in `~/.fonts`. Just `/usr/share/fonts` and the TL versions. Neither has the 08 size. The log does not give full path names for the fonts in the case of XeTeX, which is most unhelpful ;).

Comment: If you down load the zip file from bitbucket, there are ten `.otf` files inside, of which TeX Live supplies only three.  Install the files from bitbucket, and EB Garamond will do optical sizing automatically.  The * 08 fonts are not as near completion as the * 12 fonts, though, so check the output for bad kerning or misaligned accents.

Comment: @Thérèse Thanks, but I will stick to Bohoomil's Infinality configuration for now. I trust his judgement on this stuff and there may be good reasons that his packages do not yet contain the additional files. Even if it improves output for Xe/LuaTeX, it may well cause problems elsewhere, and installing my own stuff is likely to cause other issues, too - definitely not worth it for a single font family.

Answer (score 5):

Just after a declaration such as `\setmainfont` or `\newfontfamily` is executed, the allocated family name is available in

```
\l_fontspec_family_tl
```

so you can save it under a different name for later usage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\ebgaramond{EB Garamond}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_gset_eq:NN \ebgaramondfamily \l_fontspec_family_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setmainfont{Futura} % just a very different font

\begin{document}

Some text in the main font

\begingroup               
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\ebgaramondfamily}\normalfont

Some text in EB Garamond \textit{also in italics}

\endgroup

Some text in the main font

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want also to save the family name assigned to the main font:

```
\setmainfont{Futura} % just a very different font
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_gset_eq:NN \defaultrmfamily \l_fontspec_family_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

so you can use `\defaultrmfamily` in the same way as `\ebgaramondfamily`.

Comment: Although `\l_fontspec_family_tl` is a defined interface you're probably slightly better off using `\fontspec_set_family:Nnn` for this.